# How to have Google Forms send automated email with new responses

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Form which I would like to automatically email someone when a new response is submitted. So far, I have just a simple HTML page with text in the body, however I would like the email content to include the form data as well.

Currently, this is what I have written:

```
function sendEmail(e) {


  //response
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email.html");
  var htmlText = html.evaluate().getContent();

  var emailTo = "jeffreyabr@gmail.com"
  var subject = "New SAP Role Request"
  var textBody = "This email requires HTML support. Please make sure you open it with an email client that supports HTML"
  var options = {htmlBody: htmlText};


  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, textBody, options);
```

This came from following [this basic YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H7WFkt6J4rs).

Is there more Google Apps Script that I can add to accomplish this? Can I do this from Forms or must I do it from within Sheets?

Answer (score 1):

The `e.response` object also contains the form data, which can be accessed by using `e.response.getItemResponses()`.

Then to get the question, use `getItem().getTitle()`. To get the answer, use `getResponse()`.

If you do not need the HTML response, then you can append the questions and answers to the `textBody` to display them on the email. Otherwise, you would have to add a script in your `email.html` using [HTML scripts](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_scripts.asp) or [`google.script.run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run).

**References:**

[Event Objects | onFormSubmit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1)

[Class FormResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response)